# Reading in files creates the spinning pinwheel on mac

Tags: r, read.csv

I recently upgraded my mac to `Sierra` (previously I was using Mountain Lion) and I also updated `R` to run 3.3.2 (from 3.1.2). Now, whenever I attempt to open a file in `R` I will get the spinning pinwheel and then I have to force quit `R.

It doesn't happen all the time (about 7 times out of 10) and I'm not certain why. Typically I am using something like:

```
read.csv(file.choose())
read.dat(file.choose())
```

Even if I set my working directory to the folder where the data set is, I still end up getting the problem.

Any ideas on what might be going on here?

Comment: Can you open a file using `read.csv(file = 'path/to/file')`, specifying the exact path of a file?

Comment: I haven't tried that (Didn't know it was an option). I'm trying to wrap my head around what you are saying. Basically, use read.csv() and instead of saying file.choose or saying the name of the file (e.g., "data.csv") I would simply type in the file path (in the same manner I'd be typing in the path to the folder when I set my working directory)? At the end of that it would simply be the file name or file name followed by .cvs? Thank you

Comment: No, I'm saying hard code the name/path of the file in your call to `read.csv()`.  Anyway, when running automated R scripts, you won't want a dialog box popping up anyway.

Comment: Thanks. I'll search the documentation of read.csv() to find out more specifically how I can do this. Much appreciated.

Comment: It's completely possible that there is a bug somewhere, but reading using the exact path should hopefully be a workaround for you until you can resolve this.  I upvoted your question.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I assumed there was probably bug, didn't know if others have experienced this and had a way of fixing it. I'll play with the suggestion you made as that approach is new to me.

Comment: Can you look at the memory use when you read the file? My R tends to freeze when memory use is high. I suspect you are reading a fairly large file which uses up memory, and R is not deallocating it afterwards. I often have to restart the session (command shift f10 in R studio)

Comment: I thought that might be the case but this happens when reading in even very small files (E.g., something with 20 rows and 8 columns).

Comment: Using the GUI? Several reports have appeared on R-SIG-Mac regarding difficulties. They have not so far been reproducible by the maintainers. Try the command ine method.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, using GUI (can't stand R-Studio). What is the command line method?